# Why does silencing this keyevent not stop propagation?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

One listener is to an input, the other to the document. The input listener is `keydown`, the document's `keypress`. The input event is called first and silences the event, yet the document listener is still called! Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Silence</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
        
        <script>
            var docListener = function(event)
            {
                var d = document.createElement( "div" );
                d.textContent = "documentListener";
                document.body.appendChild( d );
            }
            
            //Add key listener to document
            document.addEventListener( "keypress", docListener, true );
            
            var inputListener = function(event)
            {
                var d = document.createElement( "div" );
                d.textContent = "inputListener";
                document.body.appendChild( d );
                
                //Silence event
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            
            //Add key listener to document
            document.getElementById( "test" ).addEventListener( "keydown", inputListener, true );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at event.srcElement and event.target. You've probably got two different events being triggered, by virtue of looking for the same thing on two different elements.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? I only see the first input event fire, which I assume is what you want. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/pLJtt/

Comment: Marc B - Hmmm, didn't think about that. How would I figure out whether it's diff events? (BTW, srcElement is only in IE)

Comment: @MarcB - while it might be different events, it's not showing that when I also print the target in both event handlers. The target stays the same: `inputListener [object HTMLInputElement]
documentListener [object HTMLInputElement]`. Also, while the events might be different, the keypress event should never be fired if the keydown event is not fired first (and it shouldn't be for anything after my input listener since I stop its propagation and silence it)

Comment: @namuol I tested in chrome and got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different events. One does not interfere with the other. If you want to stop the bubbling of `keypress` you have to explicitly say so:

```
document.getElementById( "test" ).addEventListener( "keypress", inputListener, true );
```

Comment: if you look at my code, it's **exactly** the same as yours! I do explicitly stop bubbling, yet the issue still occurs.

Comment: No it's not the same, you listen to __keydown__ and I set a listener to __keypress__